# AES Encryption From Java to Node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I need to replicate **Java** encryption code using **AES/EAX/NoPadding** with **BouncyCastle** provider in **node.js**. The encrypted value will still need to be decrypted by the legacy Java decryption, so the salt and iv bytes need to stay the same length. In the **node.js** code I am able to generate the salt and secret key correctly. But I have an issue. What is equivalent algorithm to **AES/EAX/NoPadding** with **BouncyCastle**?

**Existing Java:**

```java
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext, char[] password) {
    byte[] saltBytes = "SaltString1234!".getBytes("UTF-8");
           
    final byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(saltBytes, 0, salt, 0, 16);
    
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    
    random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    byte[] iv = new byte[8]; // 
    random.nextBytes(iv); 

    String normalizedPassword = Normalizer.normalize(new String(password), Normalizer.Form.NFC);
    char[] currentPassword = normalizedPassword.toCharArray();
    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(currentPassword, salt, 1000, 128);
    SecretKey derivedKey = newSecretKey("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1", keySpec); 
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(derivedKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
    
    Provider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Cipher cipher = newCipher("AES/EAX/NoPadding", provider);
    
    final IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParamSpec);
    
    return cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
}
```

**New node.js code:**

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

function encrypt(plaintext, password) {
    const salt = Buffer.from('SaltString1234!', 'utf8').subarray(0,16);

    const secretKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password.normalize('NFC'), salt, 1000, 16, 'sha1');

    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(8);

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(
            'aes-128-gcm'/* What algorithm be equivilent to AES/EAX/NoPadding with BouncyCastle? */,
            secretKey,
            iv
        );
 
    const ciphertextWithTag = Buffer.concat([
        iv,
        cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8'),
        cipher.final(),
        cipher.getAuthTag()
    ]);
 
    return ciphertextWithTag;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the crypto module of NodeJS supports EAX mode. You can use `console.log(crypto.getCiphers())` to get the supported algorithms/modes.

Comment: @Topaco I can see that it is not supported with `crypto.getCiphers()`. So it looks like it isn't even possible without writing my own implementation of EAX in node? I was unable to find any other implementation of it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any NodeJS library that supports EAX. For JavaScript, [this](https://github.com/artjomb/cryptojs-extension) could be an option.